# when my program in any process i see 'program Not Responding' and black screen - in Windows-7

Tags: c#, winforms

when my program in any process (load csv file for example)

i see `'program Not Responding'` and i see black screen - in Windows-7

in Windows-XP i dont see it

(after this the program Continues normal)

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a long process is running, if it's running on the UI thread, that causes the application to not respond to other UI events, most notably drawing the screen. In both Windows XP and Windows 7, this will cause application to be reported as "not responding", but XP and Windows 7 handle window painting differently.

In XP, the application actually updates the screen, but in windows 7, the OS saves what the current screen looks like, then displays that on the screen using a different mechanism (for example, with Aero enabled, it actually displays the contents of the windows using textures in pseudo-3D).

In 7, this can cause applications that are not responding to display black (or the last-known screen in faded grey, depending on graphics settings) screens (because it doesn't have any up to date information). Whereas in XP, it leaves the old content up, but dragging a window over it causes shadows of the window to be displayed on the screen, because the lower window is not updating.

Update:

How do you fix it? Well, there's a bunch of different things, but if you have a method that takes a very long time:

```
private void SomethingThatTakesAReallyLongTime()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
}
```

Your event handler can look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Action)SomethingThatTakesAReallyLongTime).BeginInvoke(null);
}
```

This may not be a good idea in many cases, but it's a simple example of things you can try.

Comment: so what i can do ? can i get any sample ?

Comment: @Gold Yeah, look at background worker processes, threads, there's a bunch of solutions, I've also updated my response with a possible and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are tying up the UI thread (main thread) for an extended period of time likely because the operation is intensive (either CPU or disk).  Try moving the intensive operation (say reading file) into a second thread.  This will keep the main thread (one w/ UI) responsive to the user and OS.

There are numerous methods to accomplish this.  Using a BackgroundWorker is the simplest to implement.  This should get you started:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspxr

Esesentially you will:

1. Create a backgroundWorker
2. Create an event handler for the DoWork event and wire it to DoWork.
3. Place the CPU intensive operation inside the DoWork event handler.
4. Call the RunAsync() method of the backgroundWorker (which will keep off DoWork event)

You can get more complex with providing progress and allowing user to cancel.  Here is an example of loading large file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229675.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your main thread is working on a relatively long-running task and therefore cannot repaint the screen. Thy using a worker thread to load the csv (for this example) and you shouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, it's happening because you're trying to execute a long running process on the UI thread (which blocks the UI thread so that it can't redraw the form).

You should use some form of Threading to start the long running process on a separate thread so that the UI can continue to function.